# How can I run spark-submit commands using the GCP spark operator on kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, spark-submit

I have a spark application which i want to deploy on kubernetes using the GCP spark operatorhttps://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator. 
I was able to run a spark application using command kubectl apply -f example.yaml but i want to use spark-submit commands.

Comment: which `spark-submit` command option you are not able to map to `example.yaml` file ?

Comment: I am able to map all the options in the yaml file but using a kubectl apply command for my application would mean a large change. If i am able to do a spark-submit to the cluster directly, it would save a lot of work.@QuickSilver

Comment: were you able to find any solution to what you were looking to do?

Comment: @alex nope.. instead of using the GCP spark operator, i directly did a spark-submit to the kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 0):

There are few options mentione by [https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark](http://Docker-Spark) which can use 
see if that solves your problem

```
kubectl run spark-base --rm -it --labels="app=spark-client" --image bde2020/spark-base:2.4.5-hadoop2.7 -- bash ./spark/bin/spark-shell --master spark://spark-master:7077 --conf spark.driver.host=spark-client
```

or

```
kubectl run spark-base --rm -it --labels="app=spark-client" --image bde2020/spark-base:2.4.5-hadoop2.7 -- bash ./spark/bin/spark-submit --class CLASS_TO_RUN --master spark://spark-master:7077 --deploy-mode client --conf spark.driver.host=spark-client URL_TO_YOUR_APP
```

Comment: this uses a spark base image and not a kubernetes operator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to manipulate directly the spark-submit command that the spark operator generates when it translates the yaml configuration file to spark specific options and kubernetes resources. This is kind of the point of using the operator. It lets you use a yaml config file to run either a SparkApplication or a ScheduledSparkApplication like if it were a kubernetes resource. Most options can be set either with hadoop or spark config files in config maps or as command line arguments to the jvm in the driver and executor pods. I recommend to use this last approach in order to have more flexibility when it comes to fine tuning spark jobs